# irregularity in color extraction using python

Tags: image, python-2.7, image-processing, scipy

I am facing irregularity in color extraction from an image specifically this one [image: post360]

```
#i am finding the top prominent colors in the pic
#i am using k-means to make clusters of prominent colors
import struct
import Image
import scipy
import scipy.misc
import scipy.cluster
import urllib2, cStringIO

__all__ = ["ColorExtractor"]

def ColorExtractor(given_url):

    req_headers = {
        'User-agent':
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safar/537.36'
        }

    print "from hello"
    request = urllib2.Request(given_url, None, req_headers)
    cString_file = cStringIO.StringIO(urllib2.urlopen(request).read())

    NUM_CLUSTERS = 12
    print 'reading image'
    im = Image.open(cString_file)
    im = im.resize((200, 200))      # optional, to reduce time
    ar = scipy.misc.fromimage(im) #take into numpy array

    shape = ar.shape
    print "this is shape", shape
    ar = ar.reshape(scipy.product(shape[:2]), shape[2]) #shape it for process

    print 'finding clusters'
    codes, dist = scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans(ar, NUM_CLUSTERS) #make cluster of the image pixel i guess
    print 'cluster centres:\n', codes

    vecs, dist = scipy.cluster.vq.vq(ar, codes)         # assign codes
    counts, bins = scipy.histogram(vecs, len(codes))    # count occurrences
    all_hex_codes = []
    print "all bins:", bins
    for each_color in codes:
         all_hex_codes.append(''.join(chr(c) for c in each_color).encode('hex'))

    index_max = scipy.argmax(counts)                    # find most frequent
    peak = codes[index_max]
    print "peak:", peak
    colour = ''.join(chr(c) for c in peak).encode('hex')
    c = ar.copy()
    for i, code in enumerate(codes):
        c[scipy.r_[scipy.where(vecs==i)],:] = code
        scipy.misc.imsave('clusters.png', c.reshape(*shape))
    print 'saved clustered image'
    print all_hex_codes


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ColorExtractor("https://s16.postimg.org/y5qqemidh/Post_360.jpg")
```

everytime i run the function i get different output everytime, 
though my result is in hexcode, i have saved all the hex code in images for human eyes.

on first run i got:

[image: first_run]

on second run i got:

[image: second_run]

My code runs perfectly on other logos, complex one like apple multicolor logo etc. but this image is giving me hard time.

What could be the reason for such anamoly and what is the solution for it ?

Thank you.

Comment: What are you actually clustering? You don't describe in text what you are trying do. Are you clustering the locations, colour etc? You leave quite a bit to the reader to guess.

Comment: @kkuilla oh,i added a comment for it. basically i am using k-means to find prominent colors in the image by clustering them. that is what cluster is there for.

Comment: Yes, but what are you using as input to kmeans? What is your metric? It looks to me that you are using the pixel coordinates as input to kmeans hence you are using the pixel coordinates to group the colours. I don't think that is clear from your question...

Comment: @kkuilla yes, you are correct coordinates are stored in numpy array in the variable `ar` and then using `scipy.cluster.vq` kmeans to figure clusters

Comment: This looks like a classic example of selecting an algorithm without actually understanding it. Don't take this the wrong way but it wouldn't surprise me if someone told you that `kmeans` is used for clustering. You then chose `kmeans` because that is what people use for clustering, fed in a selection of images and hoping that is will come back with the correct result. This will only lead to an epic fail.

Comment: What you need to do is to create an `nx3` matrix where `n` is the number of pixels in your image and the columns represent `RGB`. You then cluster this matrix. You are now clustering the colours. Each point will then belong to a cluster based on its colour. You then need to map the point back to its image coordinate.